# How can I make WP Featherlight work with images like with galleries?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lightbox, featherlight.js

How can I make WP Featherlight plugin for WordPress work with images like with galleries? It allows to scroll images only when they are placed to a post as gallery. But how can I make it scroll all images in the post like all others similar plugins do?

You can download the plugin here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-featherlight/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to call `featherlightGallery()` for all images. It can be done by changing the code of the `findGalleries` function:

```
function findGalleries() {
    // Treat all images like a gallery
    $body.find( 'a[href]' ).filter( testImages ).featherlightGallery();
    ...
}
```

Optimized version of the code above for `wpFeatherlight.pkgd.min.js` file:

```
function g(){j.find("a[href]").filter(d).featherlightGallery();...}
```

Comment: Never ever change source code you don't have control over. After the next update, your changes will be lost.